# Need help on blackjack game to print out total of two cards

Tags: python, blackjack

i have a black jack game i need to make and its separated into 2 files, one deals with the card shuffle and the other is about the actual game

My issue is i can get the code to print the two cards for both the player and the dealer although i need to to be printed in a format such as this

Player's hand is 3: 1 of Clubs | 2 of Hearts

not like this

['1C', '2H']

Showing the total and seperating the cards

Here is the first file that manages the game and the other is the cards

```
import playing_cards
import random
player_hand = []
dealers_hand = []

#

# Testing code for step 1 
##card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
##print(card)


# Player

# Deal first card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()

# Append it to the player_hand list
player_hand.append(card)
# Deal second card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
# Append it to the player_hand list
player_hand.append(card)
#ADDING UP BOTH CARDS

# Display the player's hand to the screen using a simple print statement
print("Player's hand is ",  player_hand)



#Stage 3 - dealer

# Deal first card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
# Append it to the player_hand list
dealers_hand.append(card)
# Deal second card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
# Append it to the player_hand list
dealers_hand.append(card)
# Display the player's hand to the screen using a simple print statement
print(dealers_hand)
```

Here is the other file but the task says i cant mod it,, i just added it to make it a little easier to understand

```
deck = ['AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH',
        'AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD',
        'AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS',
        'AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC']

# Playing deck in use
playing_deck = []


# Function to determine whether there are any cards left in the
# deck of playing cards
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: True if the deck is empty, False otherwise
def is_empty_deck():

    # Check to see whether playing deck is empty
    return len(playing_deck) == 0


# Function to rebuild and shuffle the deck
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: Nothing is returned from the function.
def reset_deck():
    global playing_deck

    # Create new playing deck
    playing_deck = deck.copy()

    # Shuffle deck
    random.shuffle(playing_deck)


# Function to deal one card
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: A string (containing two characters) representing
# the card delt, i.e. '2H' meaning 2 of Hearts
def deal_one_card():

    # Check to see whether there are any cards left
    if is_empty_deck():

        # Rebuild and shuffle deck
        reset_deck()

    # Return a card (string of two characters)
    return playing_deck.pop(0)
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write a function to convert `1C` to `1 of Club`. You can use a dictionary to perform the mapping of suits.

```
d = dict()
domain = ['C', 'H', 'D', 'S']
image = ['Club', 'Heart', 'Diamond', 'Spade']
for i in range(4):
    d[domain[i]] = image[i]

def process(x):
    return x[0] + ' of ' + d[x[1]]

print(process('1C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dict` helps here, tremendously:

```py
def card(code):
    ref = {'C': 'Club', 'H': 'Heart', 'D': 'Diamond', 'S': 'Spade'}
    value = {'A': 'Ace', '2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four', '5': 'Five',
             '6': 'Six', '7': 'Seven', '8': 'Eight', '9': 'Nine', 'T': 'Ten',
             'J': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', 'K': 'King'}
    return value[code[0]] + ' of ' + ref[code[-1]]
```

Test:

```py
[print(card(i)) for i in deck]
```

Output:

```
Ace of Hearts
Two of Hearts
Three of Hearts
Four of Hearts
Five of Hearts
Six of Hearts
Seven of Hearts
Eight of Hearts
... ...
Nine of Clubs
Ten of Clubs
Jack of Clubs
Queen of Clubs
King of Clubs
```

#### OR:

```py
import inflect

deck = ['AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH',
        'AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD',
        'AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS',
        'AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC']

def card(code):
    ref = {'C': 'Clubs', 'H': 'Hearts', 'D': 'Diamonds', 'S': 'Spades',
           'A': 'Ace',  'T': 'Ten', 'J': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', 'K': 'King'}
    if code[0] not in [str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]:
        return ref[code[0]] + ' of ' + ref[code[-1]]
    return inflect.engine().number_to_words(int(code[0])) + ' of ' + ref[code[-1]]

[print(card(i)) for i in deck]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make adjustment with Ace when hand > 21.

**Added following Functions** to first file

```
def score_hand(player_hand):
  " Scores hand with adjustment for Ace "
  value = {}
  for i in range(10):
    value[str(i)] = i
  value['J'] = 10
  value['Q'] = 10
  value['K'] = 10
  value['A'] = 11

  score = sum(int(value[card[0]]) for card in player_hand)
  if score > 21:
    # Adjust for Aces
    adjustment = sum(10 if card[0]=='A' else 0 for card in player_hand)
    score -= adjustment

  return score

def show_hand(player_hand):
  suits = {'C': 'Club', 'H': 'Heart', 'D': 'Diamond', 'S': 'Spade'}
  names = {'2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four', 
            '5':'Five', '6': 'Six', '7': 'Seven', '8': 'Eight', '9': 'Nine', 'T': 'Ten','J': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', 'K': 'King', 'A': 'Ace'}

  score = f"Player's hand is {score_hand(player_hand)}: "
  cards = ' | '.join([f"{names[card[0]]} of {suits[card[1]]}" for card in player_hand])

  return score + cards
```

**Tests**

Example hands

```
hands = [['3S', '4H'], ['AC', '5D'], ['AC', 'KD', '2C'], ['AC', 'KD', '5C', 'AH'], ['AC', 'AH', 'AD', 'KD', '5C'], ['AC', 'AH', 'AD', 'KD', 'JC']]
for hand in hands:
  print(f"{hand} shows as ->>>>")
  print(show_hand(hand))
  print()
```

**Output**

```
['3S', '4H'] shows as ->>>>
Player's hand is 7: Three of Spade | Four of Heart

['AC', '5D'] shows as ->>>>
Player's hand is 16: Ace of Club | Five of Diamond

['AC', 'KD', '2C'] shows as ->>>>
Player's hand is 13: Ace of Club | King of Diamond | Two of Club

['AC', 'KD', '5C', 'AH'] shows as ->>>>
Player's hand is 17: Ace of Club | King of Diamond | Five of Club | Ace of Heart

['AC', 'AH', 'AD', 'KD', '5C'] shows as ->>>>
Player's hand is 18: Ace of Club | Ace of Heart | Ace of Diamond | King of Diamond | Five of Club

['AC', 'AH', 'AD', 'KD', 'JC'] shows as ->>>>
Player's hand is 23: Ace of Club | Ace of Heart | Ace of Diamond | King of Diamond | Jack of Club
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it makes a lot of sense now. I tried the example hands and it works really well but how would i use random cards rather than the set examples ?

Comment: sorry more asking how do i stoip it from printing out 5 times. Just confused how i actually print out the total for my real game

Comment: @isuckatcode--as my example demonstrate to show a hand you use: `print(show_hand(hand))`.  So you replace your current print statement for player and dealers hand as follows.  To show player's hand: `print(show_hand(player_hand))`.  For the dealer's hand: `print(show_hand(dealers_hand))`.  Does that

Comment: gOT it working thanks, 1 thing i noticed, sometimes i got error T ? any idea

Comment: @isuckatcode--can you provide the full stack trace for the error (i.e. it normally shows the line number and type of error)?